# NSPredicate to fetch child objects from an entity

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a simple data model with two entities. A parent entity called Character and a child entity called Statiscis. A Character can have multiple Statistics and each statistic can have only one parent, so the relationship is many to one.

[image: Data model]

From the view controller that displays the details of a Character I call to a new Table VC to list all the Statistics related to this Character. On this controller I have a nice SIGABRT when I try to build the fetchedResultsController: *"Unable to generate SQL for predicate (character == currentCharacter) (problem on RHS)".*

When I create the Table VC I send the managedObjectContext and the character displayed on the details VC through two properties (same name) on prepareForSegue, so in the table VC self.currentCharacter hosts an instance of a Character managed object.

```
#pragma mark - NSFetchedResultsController
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil)
    {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Statistic"];

    // Stupid predicate :(
    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"character == self.currentCharacter"];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"statName"
                                                                   ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                                                  managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                                                    sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                                             cacheName:nil];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    // Going to crash
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Core Data error: %@, %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
        abort();
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Do not know how to create the predicate, and I tried unsuccessfully several ways

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want

```
 fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"character == %@", self.currentCharacter];
```

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps:
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"character == %@", self.currentCharacter];